# Google Tag Manager link click image

Tags: css, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using `Google Tag Manager` to send an event to `Google Analytics` when you click an `<a>` or a`<button>` tag, which works fine.

However I also have an `<a>` tag wrapping an `<img>` and the event is not firing because the element getting clicked is not the `<a>` tag, it's the `<img>` tag.

I've tried to move my `.sau-btn` to the `<img>` tag but this doe not work either. I've also tried to move my a tag to act as a hotspot on top of it.

```
<a href="#" @click="openSaleOfferModal(true, 'enterprise')" style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red; background-color:green z-index:99; position:relative;"><v-img :src="require('@/assets/img/sales-banner-enterprise.jpg')" class="gtm-btn" data-gtm-category="Sales Offer" data-gtm-action="Test Link" data-gtm-label="Image Real Link One" alt="alt tag"></v-img></a>
```

How get I get my event to fire when you click anything inside of the class that it is holding?

[image: Google Tag Manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the **parent anchor tag** to not capture the event down to the **image tag**, you can call `event.stopPropagation()` on it.

By default, events do get to the most nested element through the capturing phase. Here is a link to the API :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation